# You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm Trying to create new App in appstoreconnect, 
But I'm getting Below Error

> "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps."

[image]

But I have already register Identifiers in developer.apple.com.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue since yesterday! Can I ask is it a new account?

Comment: @Steven yes it's new one

Comment: Exactly the same as me. I think the only thing we can do is wait and try again next week. Because when I press supports it redirect me to a different language then what I gave up.

Comment: @Steven Yes, because i'm day before yesterday moved one application to live, It has been going on since yesterday

Comment: well I was trying it yesterday to and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Same here guys. New account, everything setup correctly (agreements, banking, appId, certs, profiles). It looks like that it doesn't work right now

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not an answer.
I have the same problem as all of you (for 3 days). Few minutes ago I try again and work for me. 
Try again now! 
Best luck!

Comment: @Felipe Diaz Paez It's also working for me, Thanks for letting us know!